# bash -c variable does not get assigned

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
 $ bash -c "var='test' && echo $var"
```

and only an empty line is being printed.

If I execute the same command without `bash -c`

```
$ var='test' && echo $var 
test
```

the value assigned to `$var` is being printed. Could someone explain why I can't assign variables in the first example?

Comment: Just single quote it like `bash -c 'var='test' && echo $var'` and also try to run `var=foobar;bash -c "var='test' && echo $var"` you will understand what is happening

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double quotes expand variables, so your command is expanded to

```
bash -c "var='test' && echo"
```

if `$var` is empty when you run it. You can verify the behaviour with

```
var=hey
bash -c "var='test' && echo $var"
```

Switch the quotes:

```
bash -c 'var="test" && echo $var'
```